# onChange not firing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am obviously doing this wrong because nobody in the world seems to have had this problem before.

I want to run a Google Apps script when a row is inserted at the end of a sheet. I understand I need to use onChange for this, so this is what I did:

Set up a script that should run when a change is triggered:

```
function copyDownFormula(e) 
{
Logger.log('something');
}
```

Then I set the onChange trigger to in my triggers:

[my sheet triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1DAz.jpg)

And then I installed this code to install the onChange trigger when the sheet opens using the onOpen trigger:

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();
```

But for some reason when I add rows to the sheet nothing happens. I visit the Logs and they are empty. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

## onChange is back to Firing Again

**Perhaps this:**

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();
```

**Should be this:**

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyDownFormula').forSpreadsheet(ss).onChange().create();
```

---

**Try this:**

```
function copyDownFormula(e)
{

  Logger.log('ChangeType:%s Row:%s',e.changeType,SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow()); 

}
```

Setup the trigger in Current Project's Triggers in the Edit Menu.  It works.

**Or if you wish:**

You use this:

```
function triggerSetup()
{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyDownFormula').forSpreadsheet('SpreadsheetId').onChange().create();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. Now there is a different problem:

[17-11-09 22:51:08:711 PST] Execution failed: You do not have permission to call newTrigger (line 7, file "runOnOpen") [0.101 seconds total runtime]

Seems I cannot run the trigger installer from onOpen. I wanted to avoid any manual approval of triggers as there are other users using the sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: That’s weird because I’ve run the nScriptApp.newTrigger inside of an onOpen